# How to calculate the recall and precision in Entity Linking?

Tags: nlp

I am pretty confused about how to calculate the recall and precision in the process of entity linking. When we disambiguate an entity to the correct sense(T) or incorrect sense(F), we only have this two situation. But how can we get those four situations: TP, TN, FP, FN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I think the reason why the answer was avoiding you lies in the fact there are more than just two correct/not answers for the evaluation of your prediction.

[Entity linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking) is a form of [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) where there could be many possible answers, but only one of them is correct. Following the example in wikipedia, "I don't like Paris" could mean "Paris, France", "Paris, Texas" or "Paris Hilton".

Evaluating the performance of a multiclass classifier follows on from how you score a binary classifier (which only has two possible outcomes):

Table 1

```
             Actual
              0   1
Predicted 0  TN  FN
          1  FP  TP
```

Once you have this you can track the rates, in the TPR, FPR etc. for recall, precision etc. which you sound familiar with.

To evaluate a multiclass classifier, you need to **evaluate it per possible answer (class) and treat all incorrect answers as negatives**. (ref: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/evaluate-model-performance#using-cross-validation-2), [SciKitLearn](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification) )

Imagine A, B and C are the three above Paris entities (for readability). I will add the "binary treatment" next to the classification, so you can see the score is following the binary, in the same way as above.

First you would score the linker for A: Paris France.

Table 2A

```
               Actual
               A   B   C
               1   0   0
Predicted A 1  TP  FP  FP
          B 0  FN  TN  TN
          C 0  FN  TN  TN
```

Next score the B answer:

Table 2B

```
              Actual
              A   B   C
              0   1   0
Predicted A 0 TN  FN  TN
          B 1 FP  TP  FP
          C 0 TN  FN  TN
```

Finally considering C

Table 2C

```
              Actual
              A   B   C
              0   0   1
Predicted A 0 TN  TN  FN
          B 0 TN  TN  FN
          C 1 FP  FP  TP
```

Of course in your evaluator, you would automate this treatment. Good frameworks have the evaluation tools built in which will do this under the hood.

(By the way, I just imagined and created those tables as a way of illustrating it, so apologies for any errata).

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer of you. It's pretty straightforward, but I am still confused that when score the link for A, why B could be FP in the second table? Since I think when we predict A is the right answer, which also means that B is the wrong one. So, maybe B should be TN as well?

Comment: If I understand your question and you are talking about Table 2A (just labelled), "which also means that B is the wrong one" cannot be not true. If B is the "Actual" answer then it is the correct answer, and the prediction of A is wrong. Hence it was a false positive since in table 2A we are considering A as positive. So predicting A is like predicting 1/Yes/True/Correct in a binary classifier. Looking at the binary labels I added, it's Predict:1, Actual:0 which is a false positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that I understand a little bit about the idea. So, the recall for Table 2A would be 1/3?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk of the performance of these tables themselves, as they are just illustrating all possible combinations of results. In practise your system would have achieved various counts of TN's, TP's etc, as you run over your dataset, which then add up into the various rates. Recall being TPR or total TP's achieved divided by total actual positives in the test dataset.